# Return variable length array from function

Tags: c++, arduino

Been in C#-land for a while and I can't work out how to do this in C++  (in an Arduino sketch)

I would like to call a function from a library that returns a list of bytes of unknown length. Sort of like this:

```
byte devices[] = MyLib::EnumerateDevices();
```

And in the library:

```
byte[] MyLib::EnumerateDevices()
{       
   int count = 0;       

   //some code that modifies count

   static byte *temp = new byte[count];  // Assume count is 2 here

   temp[0] = 42;
   temp[1] = 44;       

   return temp;
}
```

Obviously I have all me pointers and derefs either missing or in the wrong place...

Help?

Dave

Comment: You'll need some way to pass the length of the array as well, unless you can deduce the length just from the byte sequence?

Comment: The arduino uses AVR libc which does not support new and delete: http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/FAQ.html#faq_cplusplus

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is what vectors are for:

```
std::vector<int> func()
{
    std::vector<int> r;
    r.push_back(42);
    r.push_back(1337);
    return r;
}
```

Vectors have a `size()` member function which returns exactly what you want.

If you want a pointer out of the vector, then write

```
const int *p = &vec[0];
```

(obviously, substitute `int` with whatever type you specialized the vector with.)

Comment: These days, you could shorten that to `return {42, 1337};`, if you like brevity.

Comment: @MikeSeymour well, yes. My go was only to show that "here you do stuff with the vector and then return it" :)

Comment: std::vector (and the rest of the STL) is not available on arduino.

Comment: @Craig Then you need to pass a `size_t` argument by reference.

Comment: Sorry, a bit pissed.
The question specified variable-length arrays in C++, NOT vectors!

(Feel free to delete this comment now...)

Answer (score 2):

You can't return an array in C or C++. You can return a pointer, but in this case, you would also need to return the size. Use `std::vector<int>` instead, much easier.

Comment: You can return an array, either as a struct/class member or a std::array<>.